# what does this case object requirement actually mean ?

Tags: fields

I have got a requirement as "Case field usage - 37 fields on 117 have no data" . i cant understand the meaning. Can anyone please tell me ?!

Comment: One option is to ask the person that gave you the requirement to provide information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure they (whomever gave you the requirement) meant "37 fields *of* 117 have no data." Meaning, there are 37 fields that can probably be deleted safely because there is literally no value in those fields for any record in the system. One important thing that people should do is to delete fields that are no longer used. They simply create clutter and make it more challenging to find relevant data.

Comment: Suppose i delete a field "X" which is not being used. But in future if i want it means what can i do? If i didnt delete it , i can use it in future using page layout(drag and drop). So how can we be sure that a field is not being used/wont be used in future ?

Comment: @ram451 There's a limit to how many fields you can have anyways, so it's best to delete fields, and create them as you need them. You'd have to do more work than just removing the field from the layout, such as changing field level security so they don't appear in reports and list views, and so on. Deleting the field takes care of removing it completely, and you can always re-create it later when you need it in just a few clicks.